# Would the military be more efficiant if they were unionized?

Tags: labor-economics, political-economy

I hear about the extremely long work hours in the army. I understand it hardens them for readiness for combat situations. With the technology and increase of intelligence need to operate it would a more normal work schedule be more efficient and less mistakes?

How much more would it cost the military to have union like rules?

Comment: Is a valid answer "the concept of unions cannot possibly work with the military?"  The way I look at it, the key requirement for unions to operate is the feasibility of collective bargaining.  Collective bargaining in a business that cannot ever support the possibility of a strike is going to be a monumental challenge.

Comment: Military discipline and unions are antithetical.

Comment: They cannot just add more people in a combat zone (to allow them to work shorter hours). More people = more mouths to feed, making logistics even more difficult.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this question is more to do with organizational psychology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

European countries offer a variety of different unionisation models, so provide reasonable evidence on the usual consequences of unionisation.  [Dutch military personnel are represented by a union](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2006/jan/28/careers.themilitary), for instance.

The [European Association of Military Organisations appears sanguine](http://euromil.org/military-trade-unionism-europe/) about the idea, although many European military unions don't have the right to strike (emphasis added):

> The President concluded by emphasizing that EUROMIL strongly believes
>   that **military trade unionism does not harm military efficiency**. On the
>   contrary, being represented in trade unions and professional
>   associations can enhance the [morale] and loyalty of the troops.

Less information is available about the consequences of unionisation on working hours; in general, it seems that unions appear to understand and accept the reasons for long working hours under certain circumstances.